# NullPointerException getting ActionBar inside Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-support-library

My android application has:

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="11"
   android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

My project include `android-support-v7-appcompat` library.

I created an activity (the base class is `android.app.Activity`) and extends `android.app.ActionBar.TabListener` (I know it is now deprecated), and I styled it in the Manifest, as follow:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

When inside my activity I call:

`getActionBar()`, a `java.lang.NullPointerExceptio` error appears

Answer (score 1):

Base class should be android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead `getActionBar()` because you use `appcompat` library.

Answer (score 0):

Use **getSupportActionBar()**
Because you are using **android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity**